# DELETE query returning count of records deleted

Tags: postgresql

*Using postgres 9.6.*

I am attempting to write a function that will delete records and return to the application developer the number of rows that were deleted. I have some the following demo but I keep running into a syntax issue.

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM it.animals WHERE id <5
RETURNING COUNT(id);
ROLLBACK;
```

> [2020-03-12 09:14:11] [42803] ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in RETURNING

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with deleted as (
   DELETE FROM it.animals WHERE id <5
   returning id
)
select count(*)
from deleted;
```

---

However if that is part of a PL/pgSQL function, you can use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

```
$$
declare 
  l_num_rows integer;
begin
  DELETE FROM it.animals WHERE id <5
  GET DIAGNOSTICS l_num_rows = ROW_COUNT;  
  return l_num_rows;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, With the top query I got the following error. `WITH query "deleted" does not have a RETURNING clause`